# A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, protobuf-net

This is the code to replicate the issue. Basically it fails on deserialization, with error "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization". It's kind of interesting, if I remove the following line from IExecEnv setup:

```
metaType.AsReferenceDefault = true;
```

then the test passes. But this sounds odd. Is it a limitation of Protobuf-net?

```
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
 
namespace QRM.Analytics.Serialization.Commit.Tests;
 
public class UnitTest1
{
    private interface IExecEnv
    {
        int GetId();
    }
 
    [Immutable]
    private class ExecEnv : IExecEnv
    {
        public static readonly ExecEnv DefaultEnv = new ExecEnv(1);
        private readonly int _id;
 
        private ExecEnv(int id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }
 
        public int GetId()
        {
            return _id;
        }
    }
 
    [Serializable]
    private sealed class ExecEnvSurrogate
    {
        [ProtoConverter]
        public static IExecEnv FromSurrogate(ExecEnvSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate == null)
                return null;
 
            return ExecEnv.DefaultEnv;
        }
 
        [ProtoConverter]
        public static ExecEnvSurrogate ToSurrogate(IExecEnv env)
        {
            if (env == null)
                return null;
 
            return new ExecEnvSurrogate();
        }
    }
 
    private class WithExecEnv
    {
        private IExecEnv _env;
 
        public WithExecEnv(IExecEnv env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }
 
        public IExecEnv Env => _env;
    }
 
    private void SetupModel()
    {
        var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IExecEnv), false);
        metaType.AsReferenceDefault = true;
 
        var metaType3 = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(WithExecEnv), false);
        metaType3.UseConstructor = false;
        metaType3.AddField(1, "_env");
 
        var metaType4 = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ExecEnvSurrogate), false);
        metaType4.UseConstructor = false;
 
        metaType.SetSurrogate(typeof(ExecEnvSurrogate));
    }
 
    [Test]
    public void CloneExecEnvWithSurrogate()
    {
        SetupModel();
 
        var withExecEnv = new WithExecEnv(ExecEnv.DefaultEnv);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, withExecEnv);
 
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<WithExecEnv>(stream);
 
            Assert.NotNull(clone);
            Assert.Equal(withExecEnv.Env.GetId(), clone.Env.GetId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reference-tracking is ... a massive PITA; it works in some limited scenarios, but there are situations where it becomes unreliable. It also isn't part of the core protobuf specification, but is hacked on top at the library level. For these reasons, it is not recommended, and is deprecated going forward; it cannot be made reliable, and I'd rather not encourage people to get into dangerous territory.

Comment: Thanks Marc. We are using version 2.4.6. The strange thing is if we build our code with the nuget package of Protobuf-net, there is no issue. However, if we build with the Protobuf-net source code, then we got the error message saying "MetaType.AsReferenceDefault.set" is obsolete. Any idea why?

Comment: @inethui because the main branch of the source code is v3, and that feature is - as I said - deprecated in v3; there is a v2.4 (`2.4.1`, although it is really all of the 2.4) branch in GitHub; I've checked, and that member is not marked obsolete in that branch: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/2.4.1/src/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L67

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm able to debug it with v2.4.2 source code. It fails on the following lines in method **ReadNetObject** of **BclHelpers** class:
`if (newObjectKey >= 0 && !lateSet && !ReferenceEquals(oldValue, value))
{ throw new ProtoException("A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization");
}`.
It kind of puzzles me that the **oldValue** is an instance of **ExecEnvSurrogate** but the **value** is an instance of **ExecEnv**. These two are totally different classes. Is there an easy way to fix this issue or is there a workaround of this issue?

Comment: @inethui again, the complexities and nuances here are numerous, and are part of *why* it isn't supported going forward; at this point, I'm going to say that this feature is "if it works, great; if it doesn't: don't use it"; the recommended workaround here is: acknowledge that protobuf is a tree format, not a graph format